# VBA Copy and Paste data from mainsheet into another sheet depending on Data value

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have a main sheet named `Mainsheet` and 12 other sheets, one for each month.

My `Mainsheet` may have data for the months of January or February or March, etc. I need to copy the data reflected in my `mainsheet` and paste it to one of `Jan` or `Feb` depending for which month it is.

Here is what I have so far..

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i, LastRow
    LastRow = Sheets("Mainsheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To LastRow

        If Sheets("Mainsheet").Cells(i, "E").Value = "1/20/2017" Then
            Sheets("Mainsheet").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy 
            Destination:=Sheets("Jan").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

My question is how do I continue the macro if data is for the month of `Feb` and not `Jan`? And how do I just specify the month of Jan but not a specific date such as 1/20/2017 the one in my code?

Also, how can I just copy the Range from `A5:M5` plus the rows until the last filled cell, instead of copying the whole range from `A:5` till the Last Column used?

Answer (score 1):

Well done! You've written the code to handle *one* month sheet!

Now take that chunk, copy it - but instead of pasting it underneath and replacing `"Jan"` with `"Feb"` and so on... 12 times.... do this:

```
Private Sub UpdateMonthlyData(ByVal target As Worksheet)

End Sub
```

Then paste it there, and replace `Sheets("Jan")` with `target`. You're left with this:

```
Private Sub UpdateMonthlyData(ByVal target As Worksheet)
    Dim i, LastRow
    LastRow = Sheets("Mainsheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Mainsheet").Cells(i, "E").Value = "1/20/2017" Then
            Sheets("Mainsheet").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy 
            Destination:=target.Range("A" & target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If    
    Next i
End Sub
```

Let's clean this up a bit - double-click the `Mainsheet (Sheet1)` object in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R - brings up the *Code Explorer* with [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com)), and then hit F4 to bring up its properties. Change the `(Name)` property from `Sheet1` to `MainSheet`. Now you can do this:

```
Private Sub UpdateMonthlyData(ByVal target As Worksheet)
    With MainSheet

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 5 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, "E").Value = #1/20/2017# Then
                .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy target.Range("A" & target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

`MainSheet` is a "free" global-scope object variable you got by setting its `(Name)` property to `MainSheet` - VBA creates a global-scope object named after it, and you can use it everywhere in code to refer to *that* sheet.

So what have we got here? We get a `monthSheet` parameter that's the sheet we're copying to: figuring that out is another concern of its own, and we don't need to be bothered with it. I moved the declarations closer to where they're used, and gave the declarations an explicit type, and the `With MainSheet` instruction qualifies everything that uses a dot `.` with *that worksheet* object.

Qualifying stuff is important: When it's not preceded by an explicit worksheet reference, `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns`, ...they all implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet` - and when you're working with any sheet that's *not* the active sheet, then implicitly calling upon the active sheet means trouble.

I enclosed the *`#date literal#`* with `#` instead of `"` - that's for *string* literals. By using a `#date literal#` you avoid an implicit conversion from `String` to `Date`, because `.Cells(i, "E").Value` should be a `Variant/Date`.

Next we parameterize the month and infer the worksheet:

```
Private Sub UpdateMonthlyData(ByVal monthIndex As Long)
    With MainSheet

        On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        Dim name As String
        name = MonthName(monthIndex, True)

        Dim target As Worksheet
        target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(name)

        On Error GoTo 0 'from this point onward any error bubbles up to the caller

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 5 To lastRow
            Dim monthCell As Range
            monthCell = .Cells(i, "E")
            If Not IsError(monthCell.Value) Then
                If CStr(monthCell.Value) = name Then
                    .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy target.Range("A" & target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "Cell " & monthCell.Address & " contains an error value and cannot be processed."
            End If
        Next

    End With
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "Could not find a worksheet for month " & monthIndex & "."
End Sub
```

Now the caller only needs to run a loop from 1 to 12 to process all sheets:

```
For i = 1 To 12
    UpdateMonthlyData i
Next
```

It doesn't get much cleaner than that I think :)

Now, that `.Copy` operation still doesn't do what you want it to do - but alas, this answer is long enough already! Good luck!

Comment: Mat's Mug, thank you very much for your time and explanation everything worked perfectly! Amazing!

Comment: @Tom Pleasure! Feel free to tick that green checkmark next to the answer, just underneath the up/down vote buttons :)